# Checkboxes inside a dynamic table in PHP

Tags: php, checkbox, dynamic, row

I am trying to implement CheckBoxes to each row of a dynamic table. The checkboxes are being displayed correctly but I cannot get it values when I submit.

Here is my code:

```
<tbody>
                <?php if (!empty($arr_devices)) { ?>
                    <?php foreach ($arr_devices as $devices) {
                            ?>
                        <tr>

                            <td>
                                <form action="" method="post">

                                    <input type="checkbox" name="devices[]" value="add_device">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $devices["id"]; ?>" />
                                </form>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <?php echo '<a href=selectedCustomer.php?device_id=' . urlencode($devices["id"]) . '>' . $devices["id"] . '</a>'; ?>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <?php echo '<a href=selectedCustomer.php?device_id=' . urlencode($devices["id"]) . '>' . $devices["serial_imei"] . '</a>'; ?>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <?php echo '<a href=selectedCustomer.php?device_id=' . urlencode($devices["id"]) . '>' . $devices["serial_no"] . '</a>'; ?>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <?php echo '<a href=selectedCustomer.php?device_id=' . urlencode($devices["id"]) . '>' . $devices["name"] . '</a>'; ?>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <?php echo '<a href=selectedCustomer.php?device_id=' . urlencode($devices["id"]) . '>' . $devices["manufacturer"] . '</a>'; ?>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <?php echo '<a href=selectedCustomer.php?device_id=' . urlencode($devices["id"]) . '>' . $devices["created_date"] . '</a>'; ?>
                            </td>

                        </tr>
                    <?php } ?>

                <?php } ?>

            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#usetTable').DataTable();
            });
        </script>
```

How would you receive the value of the checkbox in PHP?

Comment: First, you can't have multiple elements with the same ID, it can be safely removed. Second, HTML will only send the value if the box is checked.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton but where am I having multiple elements? I know HTML will only send the value if the box is checked but I am not receiving any values at all!

Comment: It's a loop, so every loop you are defining another checkbox with the same id. There isn't really enough details to answer why you aren't receiving any values, we need to see the whole form and the PHP side trying to process it.

Comment: How are you trying to access it? Please show us your processing code. Also, is the code you've shown wrapped in a form tag? Please show us all the relevant code. Not just snippets.

Comment: @waterloomatt I know Iam doing it completely wrong but I am totally lost! Can you please post an answer how the posted code should be wrapped  and how should I get the value in php?

Comment: @waterloomatt I was just going through it and you deleted it! May I know why?

Comment: @BMX - Added it back. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your checkbox in a form tag and submit it using a button. Looks like you are currently just clicking a link which won't submit anything besides the data in the link. I've purposely left out the links to keep things simple. Things to notice:

- consistently use `get` (or `post)` in both the form and the processing script. 
  I used `post` here but it should work either way as long as you're consistent.
- the checkbox uses an array syntax `name="devices[]"`. This allows PHP to access it like a normal array.
- The following code example is intended to run in a single script. The form posts to itself when the `action` attribute is omitted. You can easily split it into a form and processing script by adding the `action` attribute to the form which points to the processing script. Finally, you'll have to cut/paste the PHP code under the form into the processing script.

Script:

```
<?php

// Not sure what your data source is, so I've just hardcoded an array for now. 
$devices = [
    ['id' => 1],
    ['id' => 2],
    ['id' => 3],
];
?>
<!-- I decided to use `post` here but `get` would work too as long as you're consistent. -->
<!-- Also, notice I didn't include an `action` here. If you don't, it will submit to itself; which I wanted to do in this case to keep it as simple as possible. -->
<form method="post">
    <?php foreach ($devices as $device): ?>

        <div>
            <label>
                <!-- Give it a name using the array syntax. -->
                <input type="checkbox" name="devices[]" value="<?php echo $device['id']; ?>">

                <!-- Output a label. -->
                <?php echo $device['id']; ?>
            </label>
        </div>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form">
</form>

<?php
// The form was submitted, so process it. 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    // At least 1 _checked_ checkbox was submitted.
    // If no checkboxes were checked, this array would not exist. That's why you should check for its existance before trying to access it.
    if (isset($_POST['devices']) && is_array($_POST['devices'])) {

        // Loop over the array to access each selected item.
        foreach ($_POST['devices'] as $deviceId) {
            var_dump($deviceId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will take a look at it latest tomorrow!

Comment: its displaying like this : string(2) "82" 82

Comment: How can I remove that string(2) and "82", so that it displays only the value 82?

Comment: Notice `var_dump($deviceId);` Just change that to `echo $deviceId;`

Comment: fixed it eralier

Answer (score 2):

You have to wrap your `table` in `form`

```
<form action="/" method="post">
  <table>
    <tbody> 
      <?php 
      if (!empty($arr_devices)) {
        foreach ($arr_devices as $devices) { ?>
        <tr>
          <td>
              <input type="checkbox" name="devices[]" value="<?php echo $devices["id"]; ?>">
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo '<a href=selectedCustomer.php?device_id=' . urlencode($devices["id"]) . '>' . $devices["id"] . '</a>'; ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo '<a href=selectedCustomer.php?device_id=' . urlencode($devices["id"]) . '>' . $devices["serial_imei"] . '</a>'; ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo '<a href=selectedCustomer.php?device_id=' . urlencode($devices["id"]) . '>' . $devices["serial_no"] . '</a>'; ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo '<a href=selectedCustomer.php?device_id=' . urlencode($devices["id"]) . '>' . $devices["name"] . '</a>'; ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo '<a href=selectedCustomer.php?device_id=' . urlencode($devices["id"]) . '>' . $devices["manufacturer"] . '</a>'; ?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?php echo '<a href=selectedCustomer.php?device_id=' . urlencode($devices["id"]) . '>' . $devices["created_date"] . '</a>'; ?>
          </td>
        </tr>
      <?php 
        }
      } ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

In your code you create a new form for each device. That has no sense if you want to submit an array of cheked devices. All of checkboxes has to be inside a single form element.